# Format json file proberly and parse it to java

Tags: java, android, json, gson

For an Android App I'm working on I need to parse json files with various informations to my App, for now the files look like this:

```
{
    "R6":{
        "Typ": "KnotenRaum",
        "ID": 1,
        "X-Koor": 3,
        "Y-Koor": 11,
        "Ebene": 0,
        "Kantenliste": [ "m7" ],
        "GruppenID": 1,
        "Raum": {
            "Nummer": "A.00.01",
            "Typ": null,
            "Person": null
        }
    },
    "H107":{
        "Typ": "KnotenTreppe",
        "ID": 115,
        "X-Koor": 7,
        "Y-Koor": 3,
        "Ebene": 1,
        "Kantenliste": [ "h108","b1002" ],
        "GruppenID": 1,
        "Raum": {}
    }
}
```

As this is my (or to be more specific our) first time using json I'm not sure if this is a "good" way of formating the file. The problem  is, that I don't only have 5 or 10 objects but i guess hundreds, so i think using specifiers like "H107" is the wrong way and I should just put it all into one large array?

And second: if I put it in such an array, what is the best way to parse it to java?
I don't need class objects (at least not necessarily) as all those data will be stored in a sqlite database when the app runs for the first time.

I found some examples but mostly those only consist of one object and are a lot simpler than my resulting json file I guess.

Comment: Its better to move "R6" and "H107" inside objects and put this data into an array.

Comment: Thank you, thought that would be the case, thou i did not know if i would need a specifier for the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be wise to store the data into Objects.
It's easier to insert objects into SQLdatabase as well as making a JSON objects array.

Andhere is a nice tutorial on the subject:
[Android JSON tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html)

Answer (score 1):

H107 and R6 are object names?

I think this can be a array with multiple objects where "R6" can be a JSON key on object.

for example:

```
[
  {
    "name": "R6",
    "Typ": "KnotenRaum",
    "ID": 1,
    "X-Koor": 3,
    "Y-Koor": 11,
    "Ebene": 0,
    "Kantenliste": [
      "m7"
    ],
    "GruppenID": 1,
    "Raum": {
      "Nummer": "A.00.01",
      "Typ": null,
      "Person": null
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "H107",
    "Typ": "KnotenTreppe",
    "ID": 115,
    "X-Koor": 7,
    "Y-Koor": 3,
    "Ebene": 1,
    "Kantenliste": [
      "h108",
      "b1002"
    ],
    "GruppenID": 1,
    "Raum": {}
  }
]
```

About objects I recommend you use an object to represent this JSON, is more readable and more easy to save on SQLite, you can use a framework like Jackson or GSON to parse this JSON automatically into objects.

Comment: First: Thank you very much! Second: So you say i should use a java class to represent the json object 1:1? At the moment i have a java class that is quite close, but not exactly the same, as wanted to make the class more fitting for later use, not exactly for the one time readout. Sorry if i'm talking bullshit, I have very little JSON and java experience, learning it all on the fly

Comment: Your approach is correct. Save only necessary information on the java class based on this JSON, in many cases the JSON returns more information that you really need.

Comment: Thank you very much, unfortunately i cannot upvote because i don't have enough reputation but please feel your answer thumbed up :)